# Local Debian Based Web Server. Slow when accessed via domain name, but fast via local IP

Tags: debian, ip, web

I have a local web server and the following situation:

- Accessing web server externally via domain name and IP works
- Accessing web server internally via local IP works
- Accessing web server internally via external IP works
- Accessing web server internally via domain name is ***SLOW***

I know I can just edit the HOSTS file on all the machines here but that is not a solution for me. (I could also set up a DNS server, but I've tried and I can't get it to work, it's a pain)

Any idea *why* this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's timing out trying to resolve. You can either add it to `/etc/hosts` or specify a DNS server (you could even use Google's public DNS `8.8.8.8`)

Comment: How easy/hard is it to set up a local dns server?

Comment: it's not hard... apt-get install bind9 ; and check on how to add local zones to it plenty of tutorials

Comment: But why does it time out to resolve?

Comment: because the server is going externally to reach an internal host. It can cause problems. It would be suggested to either add the IP address in your hosts file or the router's host file. You could also run an internal DNS server such as bind9, have your DHCP pool hand it out and have the domain name as an internal IP address in your local DNS server.